# Adjust div size directly off image, break text below

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the div directly off an image dimension, causing any text below the image (inside the div) to break a line if needed.

It may sound confusing so let me try to explain it better. Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tpy50uae/

If you notice, the first box is taking up a lot of unnecessary space. It's extending to the max-width of 500px when in reality, I would just want it to extend around the image. Here's the code:

```
.grid li {
width: auto;
max-width: 500px;
min-width: 200px;
}
.grid img {
max-width: 500px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you notice the .grid li has a max-width and min-width. However, it seems the div is automatically extending to the max-width based on the text. What I want it to do is extend itself around the image and then cause all the text to break a line in order to fit the width of the image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS property [word-break: break-all;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) in the below class

```
.grid .description{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to make a couple of amendments within your CSS.

The `div` containing the text is a block element and therefore will always want to fit 100% of the width clearing both sides.

Something like this should fix it all up:

```css
.grid li {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.grid img {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.grid li .pinfo {
  display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tpy50uae/1/)